# evaluation of the sum of KroneckerDelta

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, assumptions

I need help. I need to know why the next code doesn't simplify in *Mathematica* 10 but it does in *Mathematica* 8. I need some similar in version 10. What can I do?

```
Assuming[0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers, 
        FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]]]
```

Comment: This doesn't simplify for me in either V8 or V10. However, in V10 `Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]` automatically simplifies to `f[m] UnitStep[-m + nn]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It does not simplify because nn stays there instead of n. Put n and it simplifies.

Answer (score 7):

Strangely, although

```
Assuming[0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers, 
   FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]]]
```

does not simplify,

```
Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]
(* f[m] UnitStep[-m + nn] *)
Assuming[0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers, FullSimplify[%]]
(* f[m] *)
```

does.  This constitutes a work-around, if needed.  This two-step process was suggested in part by the comment by [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march).

**Addendum**

An even simpler approach is to move the assumptions inside `FullSimplify`

```
FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}], 
    0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers]
(* f[m] *)
```

Dropping the assumptions entirely also works, although not so cleanly.

```
FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]]
(* Piecewise[{{f[m], m <= nn}}, 0] *)
```

**Second Addendum**

As one might expect,

```
FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}], 
    Assumptions -> 0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers]
```

also simplifies properly.  But,

```
$Assumptions = 0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers;
FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]]
```

does not.  This may be a bug.

**Third Addendum - v10.3**

No change in behavior for

```
$Version
(* 10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015) *)
```

**Fourth Addendum - v11.0**

With

```
$Version
(* 11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016) *)
```

the code

```
Assuming[0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers, 
    FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]]]
(* f[m] UnitStep[-m + nn] *)
```

now does simplify, although

```
$Assumptions = 0 <= m <= nn && m ∈ Integers;
FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[m, n] f[n], {n, -Infinity, nn}]]
```

still does not.